# How can thread already be started?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a single instance thread class.

```
public class LogThread extends Thread{

    private static LogThread instance = null;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    private final static Object instanceLock = new Object();

    public static synchronized LogThread getInstance(){
        synchronized(instanceLock){
            if(instance == null)
                instance = new LogThread();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public run(){
        //Doing some run stuff
        //Once run is finished

        synchronized(instanceLock){
            isRunning = false;
            instance = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        synchronized (instanceLock){
            if(!isRunning){
                isRunning = true;
                super.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling start from another thread each time i get the instance, and every once in a while i get a IllegalThreadStateException in com.......LogThread.start, line x Thread already started.

How can the thread already be started if I set isRunning before starting the thread AND synchronize   it based on instanceLock.

EDIT::
I have edited my getInstance() to below:

```
 public static synchronized LogThread getInstance(){
     synchronized(instanceLock){
         if(instance == null){
             instance = new LogThread();
             instance.start();
         }
     }
 }
```

it should stop any attempts to start a thread that is already started.

Comment: Should actually be impossible in your case, are you ever setting `isRunning` back to `false`? E.g. in `run()`

Comment: yes i am setting isRunning to false, right before i set the instance to null inside a sync thread, will post updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence would be this:

- Thread A calls `getInstance`. Thread A takes the lock for a while, time to check that `instance` is not null, which it isn't at this point.
- Thread LogThread completes it's execution, `isRunning` is set to false. `instance` is set to false, but is still retained by Thread A
- Thread A calls `start` on the instance. `isRunning` is false, therefore `start` is called, hence the crash.

A quick fix would be to not set `isRunning` to false, since there is never any good reason for that instance to be available for starting again. It should then be renamed `isStarted` for consistency with what it does.

A proper solution would be to use a `newSingleThreadExecutor`, as suggested by @Mani

Comment: Thanks for the info. I decided to go with a slightly different implementation where I start the thread in the getInstance()

Answer (score 0):

```
It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
     * In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
     * execution.
```

From [Thread.start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

You should not start the thread , which is already started. even though the thread completes it work ( run completed).

It simply checks the `threadStatus` and throw exception

```
  if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

If i understands clearly, you want to make sure only one thread spend for this task, and you want to reuse the same thread.
 IMHO , you have two choices,

Option 1: Create new thread each time. make sure the previous thread is completed its work. It is expensive since creating new thread each time is expensive

Option 2: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` use this. this will make sure only one thread is created.

And in general , Avoid extend thread, use `Runnable` .

If you want to use only one thread. and have lot of Jobs. you could use the following.

```
class LogJob implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your Job
    }
}

  ExecutorService singleThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
LogJob job = new LogJob();
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    singleThread.submit(job);
}
singleThread.shutdown();
```

// For Demo i have put it in loop. You can just call `singleThread.submit(job);` . At max only one Job would run at any given time. and all your jobs would compelte.

You don't need any Sync block / method

Comment: the code in start checks if it has been started yet (isRunning bad choice of variable, should be isStarted). so if it has not started yet, it should call super.start() otherwise do nothing

Comment: Irrespective of varaible name, when you set back the variable to false, the super.start would call again which will try to start the thread which is already completed. which is wrong

Comment: I updated the question before, the only time i switch the isRunning to false, is right before i set instance to null, and this is in a synchronized block,

Comment: Even though you set instance == null , what about the threads already holding instance and waiting in start syncronized block . Once the current thread came out of run, it would release lock and others waiting will start the same thread.